# Select query ro get d-m-Y date value in php?

Tags: php, sql

In my DB entry_date column field has d-m-Y format date values. i need to get those date values by filter in php.

```
$from_date= date("d-m-Y", strtotime($from_date));
$to_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($to_date));
$res=mysqli_query($con,"select * from sv_customer where entry_date>='$from_date' and entry_date<='$to_date' ");
```

Comment: and where are `$from_date` and `$to_date` initially derived?

Comment: from date input field ``` <input type="date" class="form-control" id="from_date" name="from_date" value="<?php echo $from_date; ?>" > <input type="date" class="form-control" id="to_date" name="to_date" value="<?php echo $to_date; ?>" > ```

Comment: Don't store dates as VARCHAR. Use `date` type.

Comment: The snippet of code posted in a comment also features these previously undefined variables. Are you using POST or GET in the form? Are these variables derived from either a POST or GET request or by other means?

Comment: MySQL cannot properly parse dates unless they're in a proper date format in a date field, or if you use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), which is much slower. Store it properly, and then you can format it however you want when you retrieve it.

Comment: i cant change after 2000 records inserted bro. is there any way to retrive that date value by sql

Comment: Add a new column with the correct type, then convert the values using SQL and drop the old column.

Comment: get method @RamRaider bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `date` type for storing dates in your database. Do not store them as text. If you have already made this mistake then you need to rectify it.

First add a new proper column:

```
ALTER TABLE `sv_customer`
    ADD COLUMN `entry_date_conv` DATE NULL AFTER `entry_date`;
```

Then convert the data:

```
UPDATE sv_customer SET entry_date_conv = STR_TO_DATE(entry_date,'%d-%m-%Y');
```

Now you can use the new column in your WHERE clause:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('select * from sv_customer where entry_date>=? and entry_date<=?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $from_date, $to_date);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
```

Once everything is tested that it works, you can drop the old column and rename the new one to take its place.

Answer (score -1):

$time = strtotime('16-10-2020');
  $newformat = date('d-m-Y',$time);

Don't use "strtotime()" in date() format instead follow this pattern and select database row type as date and then compare.